# SignInWithCustomToken with auth emulator returns auth/invalid-custom-token

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-cli

I am trying to auth using emulator with a firebase custom token sent from functions to a web page.

But it returns a **HTTP400** from `www.googleapis.com` when i use it with `signInWithCustomToken();`.

```js
/** BACKEND SIDE **/
  const token = await createFirebaseToken(userid);
  res.status(200).send(token);

/** FRONTEND SIDE **/
  const res = await axios.post(endpoints.signin,{/* oauth data*/});
  await document.fApp.auth().signInWithCustomToken(res.data); /* HTTP400 here */
```

The custom token is decoded as below:

```json
{
  "https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/google.identity.identitytoolkit.v1.IdentityToolkit",
  "iat": 1605605206,
  "exp": 1605608806,
  "iss": "firebase-auth-emulator@example.com",
  "sub": "firebase-auth-emulator@example.com",
  "uid": *userid*
}
```

Is it supposed to send to googleapis.com rather than the local emulator?

I did set firebase web config with `authDomain:"localhost:9099"`, and used powershell env to point `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` to a service-account.json, throw me a warn on startup though:

> Your GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable points to ***. Non-emulated services will access production using these credentials. Be careful!

Get also this warn 3 times when i call `admin.auth().createUser()`, dunno if that's related:

> Received service account token ***strange token not from service-account.json*** Assuming that it owns project *** my project-id ***

Comment: Just figured that auth emulator has been released 22 days ago. :S
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/releases/tag/v8.14.0

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Forgot to set

```
firebase.auth().useEmulator('http://localhost:9099');
```

as [stated in the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_auth?hl=en#android_ios_and_web_sdks).

Now customToken are sent to the emulator.

Comment: Thanks for you answer! It helped me. 

One comment: last slash (`/`) in the URL was causing an error ("firebase.auth().useEmulator() unable to parse host and port from URL") in react-native firebase library. 

This worked for me `firebase.auth().useEmulator('http://localhost:9099')`